# Segregate data in the array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I currently have an array that composes of mix breeds of cats and dogs

```
MixedBreed[] = [catbreed1,catbreed2,catbreed3,dogbreed1,dogbreed2,dogbreed3]
```

what i want to achieve is to segregate or divide these breed into different array.

Like

```
CatBreed[] = [catbreed1,catbreed2,catbreed3]
DogBreed[] = [Dogbreed1,Dogbreed2,Dogbreed3]
```

and finally rearrange these data into one array like this:

```
Allbreeds[] = [CatBreed[catbreed1,catbreed2,catbreed3],DogBreed[dogbreed1,dogbreed2,dogbreed3]]
```

I'm new to ios development and i'm currently studying ways to do this,
what i've thought about is having a multiple for loop to check the breed of each animals.
I also don't know what is the appropriate title for this question. I'm sorry.

Comment: What is `AllBreeds` exactly? Because `CatBreed[catbreed1,catbreed2,catbreed3]` is unclear. Is that's a key:value (then `AllBreeds` is a `NSDictionary`)? Are the Breed (cat/dog) of the same Class and just something differs (an enum ?) subclasses of the same parent class?

Comment: all of them are array in one same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please try this to segregate the array based on the type, I am assuming that CatBreed and DogBreed are Classes. I have given catbreed segregation same way you can do dogbreeds also

```
let catbreed1 = CatBreed()
let catbreed2 = CatBreed()
let catbreed3 = CatBreed()

let dogbreed1 = DogBreed()
let dogbreed2 = DogBreed()
let dogbreed3 = DogBreed()

let mixedBreed = [catbreed1,catbreed2,catbreed3,dogbreed1,dogbreed2,dogbreed3] as [Any]
var catBreedArray = [CatBreed]()
for (index, element) in mixedBreed.enumerated() {
  if element is CatBreed {
    catBreedArray.append(element as! CatBreed)
  }
}

print(catBreedArray)
```

Comment: I'm looking for more dynamic and less declaration. i think this is written in swift. what i'm saying is that the catbreed might have 3 or more breed.

Comment: We can make it as a function and pass Breed Type and the array as params.
I don't have the data available that is why I declared like this, I hope you will be getting it from somewhere that case you can avoid the declarations.

Comment: @stackoverflowlawrence Hi once you find a better answer please update it here.